# pay online with ngcart angularjs and php

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm using ngcart

http://ngcart.snapjay.com/docs

to build my cart . But I dont know how to payonline . When click in checkout ,how can I get infomation of item and person in database by php code . Here is my form people input infomation .

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">                
                    <label for="">Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" required>
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">                
                    <label for="">Email</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">                
                    <label for="">Telephone</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="tel" ng-model="tel" required>
                    </div>
               <button type="submit">Checkout</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ngCart defined functions to get the product details. I have updated the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ypjrsat0/370/). For posting the values, we can use the ngCart function `ngCart.getItems()` for getting the cart details. Please refer the docs for the functions.